# TS2769 Incorrect typescript error on computed prop (Vue3, Typescript, dayjs)

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, linter, dayjs

I have an issue with a typing in a Vue3 application. The component is a datetime picker using the input with type datetime-local. My application uses Dayjs for handling dates. So the prop `modelValue` is of type dayjs.Days which contains a function called `format` to convert the value to an string (just like any other date-lib). When accessing `format` my IDE recognizes the function and does not complain but cooperates. My browser on the other hand is and says the following:

```
src/shared-components/DatetimePicker.vue:24:93
TS2339: Property 'format' does not exist on type '{}'.
    22 |
    23 |         const value = computed<string>(() => {
  > 24 |             return props.modelValue && props.modelValue instanceof dayjs ? props.modelValue.format() : "";
       |                                                                                             ^^^^^^
    25 |         });
    26 |
    27 |         return {
```

I have no idea why and have checked the values and their types lots of times now. Is this a Vue3 issue or am i wrong here? Some pointers or solutions would be much appreciated!

This is my component:

```
<script lang="ts">
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import { defineComponent, computed, PropType } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
    name: "DatePicker",
    props: {
        modelValue: {
            type: Object as PropType<dayjs.Dayjs>,
            required: true
        }
    },
    setup(props, context): any {
        function onInput(value: string): void {
            context.emit("update:modelValue", value === "" ? null : dayjs(value));
        }

        const value = computed<string>(() => {
            return props.modelValue && props.modelValue instanceof dayjs ? props.modelValue.format() : "";
        });

        return {
            onInput,
            value
        };
    }
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What confuses me a bit, you define the type as dayjs.Dayjs, but then check for intanceof dayjs. Shouldn't this be dayjs.Dayjs instead? On the other hand, why does it then evaluate to true...

Comment: Exactly! The instance of check is straight from the docs btw an can be removed i think.

Answer (score 0):

Updated typescript to latest version and the error was gone.